# Incorrect ordering using columnar transposition

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to use columnar transposition to encrypt text using a key.
I found an example for doing this which looks correct to me but it is not ordering as I would expect. 
I have only been learning Java for a few months so I might be missing something.

I've tried different four letter strings as I was only proposing to keep the key to four characters. It seems to order as expected in some cases but not all.

```
public static int[] arrangeKey(String key) {
    String[] keys = key.split("");
    Arrays.sort(keys);
    int[] num = new int[key.length()];
    for (int x = 0; x < keys.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < key.length(); y++) {
            if (keys[x].equals(key.charAt(y) + "")) {
                num[y] = x;
                break;   
            }
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Using String key = "live";

num array is returned as **2130**

I would expect eilv to output a num array of 3102 as the initial array values are e=3, i=1, l=0, v=2 ("live")
Why does the Arrays.sort array return 2130?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the transposition to happen as per your requirement (3102 for "live"), you need to assign

```
num[x] = y
```

instead of

```
num[y] = x;
```

The reason is that the original positioning of characters is held by the variable x, and the sorted position is held by the variable y.

A small suggestion , naming the variables appropriately instead of 'x' and 'y' would have helped you debug the code better and faster. Plus it makes it easy for others to understand as well. I don't mean this in a wrong way, or to offend you. Just sharing my experience as a developer that naming variables and methods appropriately helps a ton.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and advice. No offence taken, it's great to get some helpful pointers.